# Zend Server 5.6 cartridge will not start due to permissions

Tags: openshift

Recently I have noticed that my Zend Server 5.6 cartridge will not start properly with what looks like permissions issues.  I have been hands off of my openshift application for quite some time and have not made any modifications.  How can I get the zend-5.6 cartridge back up and running?

```
[subaru-hunterjm.rhcloud.com 28ebdd5cffd14a90914f1981af83785b]\> ctl_app restart
Cart to restart?
1. phpmyadmin-4
2. zend-5.6
3. mysql-5.1
?  2
Restarting Zend Server Deployment daemon
zdd is not running
Starting Deployment [FAILED]
CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to restart Zend Server Deployment daemon
Restarting Zend Server Monitor node
monitor is not running
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/zshm_CollectorUptimeSHM_*': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/zshm_MonitorDumpHash_*': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/zshm_monitor_ZMRequestsStatContainerSHM_*': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/monitor.app': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/monitor.wd': Permission denied
Starting Zend Server Monitor node [FAILED]
CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to restart Zend Server Monitor node
Restarting Apache
httpd: Syntax error in -C/-c directive: Syntax error on line 27 of /var/lib/openshift/28ebdd5cffd14a90914f1981af83785b/zend/configuration/etc/conf.d/zendserver_php.conf: Could not open configuration file /usr/local/zend/etc/sites.d/zend-default-vhost-80.conf: Permission denied
CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to restart Apache
Restarting Zend Server JobQueue daemon
jqd is not running
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/jqd.app': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/jqd.wd': Permission denied
Starting JobQueue [FAILED]
CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to restart Zend Server JobQueue daemon
Restarting Zend Server Console
lighttpd is not running
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/lighttpd.app': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/zend/tmp/lighttpd.wd': Permission denied
spawn-fcgi: opening PID-file '/usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/tmp/php-fcgi.pid' failed: Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `/usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/tmp/php-fastcgi.socket': Permission denied
Starting Zend Server GUI [Lighttpd] [FAILED]
CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to restart Zend Server Console
CLIENT_RESULT: Zend Server 5.6 restarted successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like answer us in the line:

```
httpd: Syntax error in -C/-c directive: Syntax error on line 27 of /var/lib/openshift/28ebdd5cffd14a90914f1981af83785b/zend/configuration/etc/conf.d/zendserver_php.conf: Could not open configuration file /usr/local/zend/etc/sites.d/zend-default-vhost-80.conf: Permission denied
```

Can you please give read access to the user running the server? If you don't see any security problem with that you could grant read access to everyone

```
chmod +r /usr/local/zend/etc/sites.d/zend-default-vhost-80.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering, I realized that OpenShift no longer supports zend server 5.6, so they probably broke it on purpose.

I created a new application on the OpenShift website with the newer version of zend server and  restored my old app to it. Seems to work fine now.